# Bug or Missing something?

Tags: android, animation, flip, playing-cards

I have coded an application where cards can be flipped to show the front and back of the card. In this application, I have 12 cards. Something I don't understand is that, when I click on any card, and then click on another following card, the following card would display the front card twice before displaying the back of the card upon click. For E.g. I click on imgFront, then i proceeded to click on imageView1(Front), by right it should show imageView2(Back), however it shows imageView1(Front). If I have only one card in the application, it would work as expected. E.g. I click on imgFront, it would show imgBack and vice versa. Any ideas?

Java:

```
import android.animation.AnimatorInflater;
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageView imgFront;
ImageView imgBack;
ImageView imageView;
ImageView imageView2;
ImageView imageView3;
ImageView imageView4;
ImageView imageView5;
ImageView imageView6;
ImageView imageView7;
ImageView imageView8;
ImageView imageView9;
ImageView imageView10;
ImageView imageView11;
ImageView imageView12;
ImageView imageView13;
ImageView imageView14;
ImageView imageView15;
ImageView imageView16;
ImageView imageView17;
ImageView imageView18;
ImageView imageView19;
ImageView imageView20;
ImageView imageView21;
ImageView imageView22;







boolean isBackVisible = false; // Boolean variable to check if the back image is visible currently

AnimatorSet setRightOut;
AnimatorSet setLeftIn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setRightOut = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getApplicationContext(), R.animator.flight_right_out);
    setLeftIn = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getApplicationContext(), R.animator.flight_left_in);

    imgFront = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFront);
    imgBack = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgBack);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    imageView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    imageView5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    imageView6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
    imageView7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
    imageView8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
    imageView9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
    imageView10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
    imageView11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView11);
    imageView12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView12);
    imageView13 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView13);
    imageView14 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView14);
    imageView15 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView15);
    imageView16 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView16);
    imageView17 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView17);
    imageView18 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView18);
    imageView19 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView19);
    imageView20 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView20);
    imageView21 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView21);
    imageView22 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView22);




    imgFront.setOnClickListener(this);
    imgBack.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView2.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView3.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView4.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView5.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView6.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView7.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView8.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView9.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView10.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView11.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView12.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView13.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView14.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView15.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView16.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView17.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView18.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView19.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView20.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView21.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView22.setOnClickListener(this);



}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {


        case R.id.imgBack:
            if (!isBackVisible) {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imgFront);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imgBack);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = true;
            } else {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imgBack);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imgFront);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = false;
            }
            break;

        case R.id.imageView2:
            if (!isBackVisible) {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imageView);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imageView2);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = true;
            } else {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imageView2);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imageView);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = false;
            }
            break;

        case R.id.imageView4:
            if (!isBackVisible) {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imageView3);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imageView4);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = true;
            } else {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imageView4);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imageView3);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = false;
            }
            break;

        case R.id.imageView6:
            if (!isBackVisible) {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imageView5);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imageView6);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = true;
            } else {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imageView6);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imageView5);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = false;
            }
            break;

        case R.id.imageView8:
            if (!isBackVisible) {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imageView7);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imageView8);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = true;
            } else {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imageView8);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imageView7);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = false;
            }
            break;

        case R.id.imageView10:
            if (!isBackVisible) {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imageView9);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imageView10);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = true;
            } else {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imageView10);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imageView9);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = false;
            }
            break;

        case R.id.imageView12:
            if (!isBackVisible) {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imageView11);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imageView12);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = true;
            } else {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imageView12);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imageView11);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = false;
            }
            break;

        case R.id.imageView14:
            if (!isBackVisible) {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imageView13);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imageView14);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = true;
            } else {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imageView14);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imageView13);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = false;
            }
            break;

        case R.id.imageView16:
            if (!isBackVisible) {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imageView15);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imageView16);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = true;
            } else {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imageView16);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imageView15);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = false;
            }
            break;

        case R.id.imageView18:
            if (!isBackVisible) {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imageView17);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imageView18);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = true;
            } else {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imageView18);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imageView17);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = false;
            }
            break;

        case R.id.imageView20:
            if (!isBackVisible) {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imageView19);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imageView20);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = true;
            } else {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imageView20);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imageView19);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = false;
            }
            break;

        case R.id.imageView22:
            if (!isBackVisible) {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imageView21);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imageView22);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = true;
            } else {
                setRightOut.setTarget(imageView22);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(imageView21);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = false;
            }
            break;




    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:clickable="true">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgFront"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:src="@drawable/front"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgBack"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgBack"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:alpha="0"
    android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgBack" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="135dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/front"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgBack" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="265dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/front"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgBack" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/front"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgBack" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="135dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/front"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgBack" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="265dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/front"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgBack" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/front"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgBack" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="135dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView13"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/front"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView14"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView14"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgBack" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="265dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView15"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/front"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView16"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView16"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgBack" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView17"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/front"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView18"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView18"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgBack" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="135dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView19"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/front"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView20"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView20"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgBack" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="265dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView21"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/front"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView22"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView22"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgBack" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Animation:Flight_Left_In:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Rotate. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="-180"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:duration="500" />

    <!-- When the roration reach half of animation, show the card -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="1"
        android:startOffset="250"/>

</set>
```

Animation:Flight_Right_Out:

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Rotate. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="180"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:duration="500" />

    <!-- Half-way through the rotation, hide the front card -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="250"
        android:duration="1" />
</set>
```

Comment: all card use a same isBackVisible

Comment: Oh i see. Problem solved thanks !

Comment: Also, learn about arrays. This code is about 20 times larger than it needs to be.